# adb - Script to add PIN but not secure start-up

Tags: android, adb

I'm trying to write a shellscript to create android emulators programatically (OS version >= 7.1.1), and I want those emulators to have a PIN but not "secure start-up".

Note that "secure start-up" is not the "lock screen" and also not the screen to unlock an encrypted device.

The secure start prevents android from booting without first inserting the PIN; lock screen is what appears after the boot up has finished.

Here's the description that shows up on Android 8.1 when you set the PIN manually on the emulator:

[image: secure start-up description]

And what shows up when the emulator starts with the secure start-up activated:

[image: secure start-up screen]

I only managed to insert the PIN using the command:

```
adb -s <emulator_name> shell locksettings set-pin 1111
```

but this also activates the secure-start and I didn't find a way to deactivate it.

Do you know a command to deactivate only the secure-start and not the PIN? Thanks!

Comment: What you call "secure start" was the password prompt for the Full Disk Encryption (FDE) which should not be used on modern devices. Instead File based Encryption (FBE) should be used,which means the the device boots directly into the OS and the shows a real lock-screen. Not sure about emulators (and how and if it uses encryption) but from my perspective you are searching a emulator that use FBE.

Comment: @Robert I updated my question. I'm not sure if the secure start-up relates to encryption. I think that the screen that asks for a PIN to decrypt the device is a different one, with a white background.